# Unable to debug WebForm program on Visual Studio 2017: Unable to attach. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x92330046

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2017

I tried to run and debug an ASP.NET Web Form project using VS 2017 and when trying to run it on IE/Chrome I am getting this error:

Unable to attach. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x92330046

[image]

The IIS express works fine when I run without debugging. But as soon as I try to start in debug mode, it shows the error.

Comment: Are you launching Visual Studio as an administrator? Right click visual Studio and click run as administrator.

Comment: I do. That's not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Launch Run command box and then paste in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`. Here delete your website folder and then try again.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It did! Thank you.

Comment: Should be:

CD %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Comment: Worked like a charm!
It should be pointed out that things (IIS Express, VS Solution, F5) HAD been working just fine and I suddenly started getting that error.
If other folks were working fine they should forget about all that 'Admin' Stuff, settings etc.  MOHSIN has your solution right here ^